# git automatically adding files in watched folders

Tags: git

I have just started using git and cannot find any way to include files that have been added into folders that are already being watched, after they were initially added.

I have to manually add the exact full path to the file which is very time consuming when you are developing and adding new files all the time.

If I use the add -A option, then it also includes files from my .gitignore !

Is it possible to have git automatically add files that are added to the watched folders ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `git add .` in the root dir is all what you need. Have you tried that?

In any case, `git add -A .` should be doing the same thing in this case. The only difference would be that `git add .` doesn't take into account removed files, which you don't have here, from what you say. But, by any means should be `git add -A .` be adding new files mentioned in .gitignore. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, "git add ." works, I was using "git add *"

Answer (score 0):

git add -A (or no -A) will never override .gitignore.

There is possibility that specific (ignorable) file is possibly added in some commit or git ignore has improper or negate pattern.

You can override .gitignore only using flag -f